# htaccess redirection issue with greek characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

**.htaccess** direction issue....

```
Redirect 301 /fr/cours /fr/cours-apprendre-le-grec-à-athènes
```

does not seem to work. I guess it's that using aphostrophes? like à that messes things up. How could I get the direction to work?

**It's supposed to redirect to** http://www.lexi-logos.gr/fr/cours-apprendre-le-grec-%C3%A0-ath%C3%A8nes when typing http://www.lexi-logos.gr/fr/cours

**but instead it redirects to**

http://www.lexi-logos.gr/fr/cours-apprendre-le-grec-%E0-ath%E8nes

Other redirections does work on the site, so the rewriting works.

Comment: @anubhava - It redirects to a page does not exists (a white page). Updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a local file encoding issue. You can try being explicit with the URL encoding:

```
Redirect 301 /fr/cours /fr/cours-apprendre-le-grec-%C3%A0-ath%C3%A8nes
```

Specifically, `%E0` is the Windows-1252 version of the `à` character and `%C3%A0` is the UTF-8 version. The htaccess file may be interpreted to be Windows-1252 charset so apache is encoding it incorrectly.

Comment: :-) Of course. Why didnt I think of that? Thank you! It worked!